# Save the Contact Form 7 Data Details of Another Site

Tags: php, database, wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using the `Contact form 7` in my **site1**.
I have added `"Contact Form Advanced Database"` Plugin to show the Submitted Records.

I have an another **Site2** in which I want to show the Contact Form.
And want to save the Data in my Site1.

Is it possible in Wordpress.?
is there any way to change the DB configuration to redirect the submission
Please share any API reference if available.

Comment: are the 2 sites on the same server/DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used `Contact Form Advanced Database` to store the Contact Form 7 Submitted Details.

[Contact Form Advanced Database](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-advanced-database/)

Answer (score 1):

One way you can solve this problem is to save your form submissions as custom posts on site 1 using the plugin [Post My CF7 Form](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-my-contact-form-7/).  Then follow this [tutorial](https://blog.ashfame.com/2010/07/display-posts-from-another-wordpress-installation/) to display the custom posts from site 1 onto site 2.